# script to execute program in loop and kill current process if time limit is exceeded

Tags: bash, scripting

I have a bash script that executes a program in a loop, but I want to set a max time limit for each execution of the program, i.e.  i just want to cancel the current execution if the time limit is exceeded but I don't want to break the entire loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is a command named timeout on my Ubuntu. You could try this:

```
timeout 1s yes
```

This will make the process yes to ends after 1 second.

Note: with this command its also possible to specify the signal as an argument.

You can also validate that the duration constaint get respected using this command:

```
time timeout 3s yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any Posix shell, including bash...

```
#!/bin/sh
while :; do
  echo starting command
  while :; do
    trap break SIGTERM
    sleep 5; kill $$  # 5 second timeout
    sleep 10 # replace this sleep with your real command
  done
  echo Command terminated, restarting...
done
```

Comment: Isn't there some `&` missing to execute the commands in parallel instead of one after the other?